# exams2pandoc error message - invalid template

Tags: pandoc, r-exams

I'm new to R and barely know enough to make the basics of R-exams work. I've successfully used it to make exams for printing (exams2pdf) and for uploading into canvas, but I keep getting the following error when I try to run exams2pandoc:

```
Error in make_exams_write_pandoc(name = name, type = type, template = template,  : 
  invalid template: exactly 9 '#-' lines required (and 0 found)
```

I don't understand what it's telling me and need a little direction.

Note - In the midst of me trying to figure out the problem, exams2pandoc did successfully output a docx file, maybe once or twice, on one of the sample files (e.g., switzerland.Rmd), but now I keep getting the error message above regardless of the file.

I'm not sure what to try at this point (e.g., tweaking one of the template files), nor do I quite know how to do that. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example? For me, `exams2pandoc(c("swisscapital.Rmd", "deriv.Rmd"))` works as intended, yielding a document `pandoc1.docx`. It seems that you have modified your template somehow. Maybe re-installing `exams` helps.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Aha! That seems to have done it. Thank you...I didn't even think of that in the midst of hurriedly trying to pull things together to produce a final exam.

Comment: Reinstallation solved it? Then I can put it into an answer that you can accept. Then the issue is flagged correspondingly on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Yes, it solved it. I'm now trying to figure out how I can remove the text "Question" on the output and simply place the actual text of the question/item on the same line as its number but I'll save that for another day. I don't know the protocol here for answers and didn't know if I should answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem sounds like the `exams2pandoc()` templates shipped along with the package have been modified/corrupted. I would recommend re-installing the `exams` package. After that `exams2pandoc(c("swisscapital.Rmd", "deriv.Rmd"))` should work again and produce a file `pandoc1.docx`.

If you want to modify the template, this is possible but poorly documented. Also the template format might change in future versions, it's still a bit ad hoc. The default template is a LaTeX file `plain.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide,color,Sweave,url,amsmath,booktabs,longtable}

\begin{document}

%% Exam ##ID##
%% ##Date##

\begin{enumerate}
#-
  \item
#-
  \textbf{##Questionheader##}\\
#-
  ##Question##
#-
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item ##Questionlist##
  \end{enumerate}
#-

  \textbf{##Solutionheader##}\\
#-
  ##Solution##
#-
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item ##Solutionlist##
  \end{enumerate}
#-
#-
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You see that `#-` lines are used to define several sections in the template file which contain certain placeholders. If you want to omit the question header it's simplest to create a file, say `myplain.tex`, where this line is commented:

```
  %% \textbf{##Questionheader##}\\
```

Analogously, other parts could be commented or modified. And then you can call `exams2pandoc(..., template = "myplain.tex")`.